# React/Redux: Where are my props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

This is my first time putting together a new app with this stack.  Previously, I worked on an inherited one at another gig where the plumbing was already setup.  My props are undefined and I need to know why.  Please make suggestions, too. Here's the abridged code:

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Root.js**

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/:filter?" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default Root;
```

**App.js**

```
const App = ({ classes }) => ( // SHOULDN'T THIS BE DESTRUCTURED FROM PROPS?
  <div className={classes.root}> // <== UNDEFINED...WHY NO PROPS?
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <AppBar />
      </Grid>     
    </Grid>
  </div>
);

export default withRoot(compose(connect())(App));
```

**withRoot.js** *(creates a default theme from Material-UI)*

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: '"Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500
  }
});

function withRoot(Component) {
  function WithRoot(props) {
    // MuiThemeProvider makes the theme available down the React tree
    // thanks to React context.
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...props} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

  return WithRoot;
}

export default withRoot;
```

Comment: no mapStateToProps in connect   - you should pass part of store

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `connect` a function that maps your state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  classes: state.classes
});

export default withRoot(compose(connect(mapStateToProps))(App));
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Material-UI.  Also, non-SFC components father upstream are getting their props okay via this.props.  I updated my post.  Does you answer still apply?

Comment: If the props are making their way to App.js, then classes should be destructured from props (provided they're in state).  Right?  Props, however, are undefined.

Comment: You are connecting your App component to the store but I think you might need to connect the higher order withRoot component to the store instead. Currently, WithRoot has no context to work with. `connect()(withRoot(App))`

Comment: Is this what you mean?  "export default withRoot(App);" and "export default compose(connect())(withRoot);"  This gives me the bogus "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function".

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `theme` object passed as prop. Material-UI uses context api, not redux.

> withTheme()(Component) => Component
>
> Provide the theme object as a property of the input component.

Comment: Isn't that already being taken care of in withRoot with this line: <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>??

Comment: isn't it a provider part (one for all) - not context 'consumer' (for components needed it) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's a bit tricky when you're connecting to context just in place where it's created. If you would use theme in AppBar then you would use `withTheme()(AppBar)` to `consume theme context`. When you need it 'at root' then probably you need `withRoot(withTheme()(App))` or use withTheme in compose beside redux's connect.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265319/using-compose-and-connect-together-in-react-js-redux

Comment: I added withTheme() inside the compose() in App.js and "withRoot(withTheme()(App))" - no luck.  Is that what you suggested?

Comment: sth like that or  `compose(
    withRoot,
    withTheme(),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`
)(App)

check structure (order matters) and props in react tab, look for `theme`

Comment: why do you expect `classes` object? is it defined elsewhere?

Comment: Material UI adds the classes to the props.   Doesn't it?  I've always deconstructed it with no problem.

Comment: when used `withStyles()`  - `theme` prop exists on App?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, sorry?  A problem is that we can't add extensions to Chrome.  So, no React of Redux tools to help :(

Comment: uppps, it hurts ... try to `console.log(props.theme)`?

Comment: Added it to App.js, "const App = ({ classes }) => {
  console.log(props.theme);" -  and get this in browser - " 'props' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: try `const App = (props) => { `

Comment: undefined...and this goes back to my original posting.  Where are the props?  I set something up wrong.

Comment: any props? from route?