# Identifier has already been declared React js

Tags: reactjs

I am still getting hang of React js. I am trying to export multiple components and i am getting this error "Identifier 'withN' has already been declared"
Here is my code for export

```
const withN =  withNamespaces()(App)
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logOut }
)(withRouter(Header));
```

Here is my import code

```
import { withN } from 'react-i18next';
```

Please tell me what is wrong.

Thanks
update:
After correcting my export statement as suggested by @octobus, I get this error attached in the image
[props undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo27U.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't import something and reassign a value to it. The reason you are getting the error is that there is already a declaration of `withN`.

Comment: This is incorrect, imports are read-only views of the exported-values

Comment: When i do that I get "withNamespaces" is not defined

Comment: @user918204 did you also import `withNamespaces` ?

Comment: I already imported withN. Do i need to import withNamsepaces as well?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza You are right sir. I misunderstood the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: @user918204 I updated my answer. What does `withN` mean, I checked the docs there is no export for `withN`

Comment: My guess, OP wants to import `withNamespaces` and for some reason he's importing `withN`...

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Yeah, that's why thought at first and answered wrongly :)

Comment: how do i export withNamspace when i already have an export for connect function?. Thats my question

Comment: @user918204 Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265319/using-compose-and-connect-together-in-react-js-redux. You can use it with compose.

Comment: I implemented compose and now i get  "Cannot set property 'props' of undefined" error. Here is my code  `const enhance = compose( connect( mapStateToProps,{withNamespaces}, { logOut })(withRouter(Header)));`

Comment: I believe it should be `const enhance = compose(withRouter, withNamespaces connect(mapStateToProps, {logOut}));` 
and then 
`export default enhance(Header);`

Comment: @octobus i still get "Cannot set property "props" of undefined

Comment: @user918204 On which line you are getting the error? That error should be independant from this one.

Comment: @octobus kindly check the image attached in the post update

Comment: The errır is entirely a different error. I am not sure about the answer. But you have a functional component. `this` keyword is a reference to something different than a class based component. Don't assign props to this.props just used it as `props` only